# Turning off screen activating the bluetooth

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.1-lollipop

Turning off / Locking the screen is activating the Bluetooth on my device.
I don't know why my device is doing this as I am unable to find any settings in Developer settings (enabling the Developer mode is the last thing I did).

Device: Honor 3C (rooted)
OS: 5.1.1
ROM: CyanogenMod 12.1

Comment: Are you using FireChat? Related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/5fjCTE4zjd4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FireChat seems to be the culprit.
Changing it's permission via Settings > Privacy (removing 'Bluetooth Change allowed' solved the issue.

Thank you @Firelord for pointing out at the right thread.