# Bluetooth switches on every time the phone locks

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, bluetooth

Since some time ago, every time I lock my phone screen or it gets locked due to not being used, Bluetooth automatically switches on.

Why could it be?

Android 4.4 on a Samsung Grand Neo Plus

Comment: Are you using FireChat? Related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/5fjCTE4zjd4

Comment: Or is it an issue specific to Samsung devices running Kitkat? [Bluetooth keeps getting turned on](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/144831/16575)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Per the info](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/nexus/5fjCTE4zjd4/sIscMjMeAgAJ) from Javier Sarten Carranza, a new update to FireChat app is the cause of the issue. The update seems to have introduced the permission to access (and manipulate) Bluetooth settings (*[android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)*) and since that permission is considered normal it stands to reason why Android wouldn't have sought user's discretion when granting the permission.

Same problem: [Turning off screen activating the bluetooth](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145023/96277)